# Passing rvalue references between functions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

I'm implementing comparison operator overloads for a particular class `foo`:

```
class foo{
public:
    foo() {};
};

bool operator==(foo&& lhs, foo&& rhs){
    // ...
    return true;
}
bool operator!=(foo&& lhs, foo&& rhs){
    return operator==(lhs,rhs);
}
```

However, when calling the `!=` operator, I get the following compilation error:

```
tester.cpp: In function ‘bool operator!=(foo&&, foo&&)’:
tester.cpp:37:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator==(foo&, foo&)’
  return operator==(lhs,rhs);
                           ^
tester.cpp:33:6: note: candidate: ‘bool operator==(foo&&, foo&&)’ <near match>
 bool operator==(foo&& lhs, foo&& rhs){
      ^~~~~~~~
tester.cpp:33:6: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
tester.cpp:37:24: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘foo&&’ to lvalue of type ‘foo’
  return operator==(lhs,rhs);
                        ^~~
```

Which seems strange to me because the  `==` operator overload takes rvalue references as arguments, so why exactly is the compiler trying to dereference them?

PS: I understand I could solve this by just passing the objects as `const &`, but for design purposes rvalue references would make more sense (`foo` is a nested helper class no supposed to be instantiated outside base class definition).

Comment: The way I understand it moving an argument tears the guts out of the original.  If you don't want to use the objects you're comparing again, this is ok.  If you do use them again later this would belong in the class of Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expressions `lhs` and `rhs` are lvalue expressions inside `bool operator!=(foo&& lhs, foo&& rhs){`. This is unrelated to the reference type of variables.

As the message says, a lvalue cannot be bound to a rvalue-reference and therefore the overload `bool operator==(foo&& lhs, foo&& rhs){` cannot be considered.

If you want to get a rvalue from a lvalue, so it can bind to the rvalue-reference, you are supposed to use `std::move`:

```
bool operator!=(foo&& lhs, foo&& rhs){
    return operator==(std::move(lhs), std::move(rhs));
}
```

Comment: Also, `operator!=` needs to return the *opposite* of what `operator==` returns: `return !operator==(...);`  If two objects are equal, they can't also be unequal.